# Capturar XML y guardar en SQLSERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una app que genera XML, los XML que genera los envía a SAP BUSINESS ONE, cuando SAP lo recibe me manda una respuesta si el envió fue correcto me manda TRUE
si este fallo me manda un FALSE con el mensaje por que fallo y me devuelve el XML 
Necesito capturar el mensaje que me devuelve y el XML y estos guardarlos en SQLSERVER para tener un log

**Ejemplo**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las respuestas que necesito capturar esto me devuelve SAP

**Código**

```
using BusinessObjects;
using Proxy.Sincronizacion;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Proxy
{
    public class XmlProxy
    {

        public async Task<string> EnviarPedido(ObtenerDatosNomina detalle)
        {
            using (WSSincronizacionClient clienteSAP = new WSSincronizacionClient())
            {
                string XmlSerializado = this.SerializarXml(detalle);

                var respuesta = await clienteSAP.EnviarDatosSAPAsync(XmlSerializado);

                return respuesta;
            }
        }

        private string SerializarXml (ObtenerDatosNomina detalle)
        {
            string serializarXml = null;

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement SAPBOElement, SAPElement;

            doc = this.CrearEncabezdoDocumento(out SAPBOElement, out SAPElement);

            this.CrearSAPElement(detalle, doc, SAPElement);

            SAPBOElement.AppendChild(SAPElement);

            //Se encarga de quitar la estructura de configuracion del XML
            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                {
                    Indent = true,
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                    IndentChars = "  ",
                    NewLineChars = "\n",
                    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
                };

                using (XmlWriter xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
                {
                    doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
                    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
                    serializarXml = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                }
            }
            return serializarXml;
        }

        private void CrearSAPElement(ObtenerDatosNomina Detalle, XmlDocument doc, XmlElement SAPElement)
        {
            //Encabezado del XML 
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "CardCode", "CE" + Detalle.cod_empl));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "CardName", "Pruebas Nomina Socio Negocio"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "GroupCode", "102"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "Currency", "$"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "LicTradNum", Detalle.cod_empl));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "Phone1", Detalle.tel_resi));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "Cellular", Detalle.tel_movi));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "E_Mail", Detalle.eee_mail));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_Nombres", Detalle.nom_empl));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_Apellido1", Detalle.ape_empl));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_Apellido2", Detalle.ape_empl));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_Nacional", "1"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_TipExt", "0"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_TipEnt", "1"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_MunMed", "05001"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_TipDoc", "13"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_RegTrib", "RS"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_AutRet", "N"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_RegFis", "R-99-PN"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_ResFis", "49"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "U_HBT_MedPag", "ZZZ"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "GroupNum", "8"));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadEncabezado(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"], "Free_Text", "Información transmistida desde el componente integrador  KACTUS nomina"));


            // Variable NumeroLinea, Se encarga de contar uno a uno cada articulo y este valor lo asigna al numero de linea del XML
            int NumeroLinea = 0;

            ////Variable LineasAfectadas, Se encarga de contar cuantos articulos hay en total y este valor lo asigna a las lineas afectadas del XML
            //int LineasAfectadas = Detalle.Detalles.Count;

            ////Detalle del XML
            //foreach (var detalle in Detalle.Detalles)
            //{
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "AdresType", "B",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "Address", "CR 65 CL 23 A  43",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "City", "Medellin",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "County", "Antioquia",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "Street", "C R 65 C L 23 A  43",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "ZipCode", "050001",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "U_HBT_DirMM", "Y",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle"], "U_HBT_MunMed", "05001",1, NumeroLinea));


            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "CardCode", "CE-1036651884",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "Name", "Luis Leon Gialdo",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "FirstName", "Luis",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "MiddleName", "Leon",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "LastName", "Giraldo",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "Address", "CR 65 CL 23 A  43",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "Tel1", "2791589",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "Cellolar", "2791589",1, NumeroLinea));
            SAPElement.AppendChild(CrearPropiedadDetalle(doc, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TablaDetalle2"], "E_MailL", "empleados@porcicarnes.com",1, NumeroLinea));
            NumeroLinea++;
        //}
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Crea las estructuras del encabezado del documento XML que se envía a SAP
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="SAPBOElement">Elemento SAPBO requerido por la integración con SAP. Parámetro pasado por referencia.</param>
        /// <param name="SAPElement">Elemento SAP requerido por la integración con SAP. Parámetro pasado por referencia.</param>
        /// <returns>Documento XML con los encabezados recién agregados</returns>
        private XmlDocument CrearEncabezdoDocumento(out XmlElement SAPBOElement, out XmlElement SAPElement)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            XmlElement ObjetosIntegracionElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "ObjetosIntegracion", string.Empty);

            XmlAttribute BaseDatosAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("BaseDatos");

            //Esta es la base de datos de sap
            BaseDatosAttr.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseDeDatos"];

            ObjetosIntegracionElement.Attributes.Append(BaseDatosAttr);

            doc.AppendChild(ObjetosIntegracionElement);

            SAPBOElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "SAPBO", string.Empty);
            ObjetosIntegracionElement.AppendChild(SAPBOElement);

            SAPElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "SAP", string.Empty);
            XmlAttribute ObjetoAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("Objeto");

            //Este Valor es la tabla  de sap que tiene los campos del xml 
            ObjetoAttr.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tabla"];

            SAPElement.Attributes.Append(ObjetoAttr);

            XmlAttribute LlaveprimariaAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("Llaveprimaria");

            //Este Valor es la llave primaria de la tabla
            LlaveprimariaAttr.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LlavePrimaria"];

            SAPElement.Attributes.Append(LlaveprimariaAttr);

            XmlAttribute ValorLlavePrimariaAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("ValorLlavePrimaria");

            //Este es el valor de la llave primaria
            ValorLlavePrimariaAttr.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValorLlave"];

            SAPElement.Attributes.Append(ValorLlavePrimariaAttr);

            XmlAttribute OperacionAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("Operacion");

            //Este valor es la accion que hace el xml que es agregar 
            OperacionAttr.Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Accion"];

            SAPElement.Attributes.Append(OperacionAttr);

            return doc;
        }


        private XmlElement CrearPropiedadEncabezado(XmlDocument doc, string nombreTabla, string nombreColumna, string valor)
        {
            XmlElement Propiedad_EncabezadoElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Propiedad_Encabezado", string.Empty);
            // Propiedad del encabezado Nombre de la tabla 
            XmlAttribute NombreTablaAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("NombreTabla");

            NombreTablaAttr.Value = nombreTabla;

            Propiedad_EncabezadoElement.Attributes.Append(NombreTablaAttr);
            // Propiedad del encabezado Nombre de la columna 
            XmlElement NombreColumnaElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "NombreColumna", string.Empty);

            NombreColumnaElement.InnerText = nombreColumna;

            Propiedad_EncabezadoElement.AppendChild(NombreColumnaElement);
            // Propiedad del encabezado se asigna el valor de la columna 
            XmlElement ValorColumnaElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "ValorColumna", string.Empty);

            ValorColumnaElement.InnerText = valor;

            Propiedad_EncabezadoElement.AppendChild(ValorColumnaElement);

            return Propiedad_EncabezadoElement;
        }

        private XmlElement CrearPropiedadDetalle(XmlDocument doc, string nombreTablaDetalle, string nombreColumnaDetalle, string valor, int lineas, int numero)
        {
            //Propiedad de detalle Nombre de tabla 
            XmlElement Propiedad_DetalleElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "Propiedad_Detalle", string.Empty);

            XmlAttribute NombreTablaADetallettr = doc.CreateAttribute("NombreTabla");

            NombreTablaADetallettr.Value = nombreTablaDetalle;

            Propiedad_DetalleElement.Attributes.Append(NombreTablaADetallettr);

            //Nombre de los campos 
            XmlElement NombreColumnaDetalleElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "NombreColumna", string.Empty);

            NombreColumnaDetalleElement.InnerText = nombreColumnaDetalle;

            Propiedad_DetalleElement.AppendChild(NombreColumnaDetalleElement);

            // Valor del campo 
            XmlElement ValorColumnaElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "ValorColumna", string.Empty);

            ValorColumnaElement.InnerText = valor;

            Propiedad_DetalleElement.AppendChild(ValorColumnaElement);

            //Lineas afectadas XML
            XmlElement LineasAfectadasElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "LineasAfectadas", string.Empty);

            LineasAfectadasElement.InnerText = lineas.ToString();

            Propiedad_DetalleElement.AppendChild(LineasAfectadasElement);

            //Numero de linea XML
            XmlElement NumeroLineaElement = doc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "NumeroLinea", string.Empty);

            NumeroLineaElement.InnerText = numero.ToString();

            Propiedad_DetalleElement.AppendChild(NumeroLineaElement);

            return Propiedad_DetalleElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y el problema cual seria?

Comment: Que no se como capturar el XML que me devuelve SAP, lo necesito capturar y guardarlo en una tabla en SQLSERVER

Comment: El xml no lo mandaste vos? y en respuesta no esta lo que devolvio SAP?

Comment: Yo envió el XML  y el me lo devuelve con un mensaje True o False Necesito capturar estas respuestas y guardarlas en una tabla

Comment: Y ese dato esta en la variable respuesta?

Comment: Si en la respuesta esta el mensaje que devuelve si fue true o false y en el XmlSerializado devuelve el XML

Comment: Y entonces vuelvo a preguntar, cual es el problema? No sabes hacer un insert a la base de datos?

Comment: Sii, señor coger el XML y guardarlo en formato XML nunca lo he hecho

Comment: Bueno en ningun lado de tu pregunta dice, no se como se guarda un xml en una base de datos ;) Podes guardarlo en un campo de tipo XML, igual lo que guardes va como texto.. no tiene mas ciencia que eso...

Comment: En sql server tienes dos posibilidades. Puedes crear una columna tipo XML que es nativo, o crear una columna tipo NVarchar(max), donde lo alojas como texto.